# Hovering over all buttons in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need the refresh_button to appear and disappear only on mouseover/mouseout on the avatar(image).
I've build this functionality and it works, however, it appears on image hover + on span hover too.
Could you please spot what's wrong?
When I use the same code on `.avatar` class it doesn't work, I think the `.r` reference is `null` in that case. I need to use vanilla JavaScript.
Thank you

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".tree").forEach(img => {
  img.onmouseover = function () {
    let refresh_button = img.querySelector(".r");
    refresh_button.style.opacity = 1;
  };
  img.onmouseout = function () {
    let refresh_button = img.querySelector(".r");
    refresh_button.style.opacity = 0;
  };
});
```

```css
#no1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 190px;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin: auto;
}

.container1 {
  width: 580px;
  font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.namefunc {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.name {
  background: #beebb3;
  border-color: #606f46;
  border-radius: 22px 0 22px 0;
  padding: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-top: 5px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 13px #222;
  width: 145px;
  color: green;
}

.name_input {
    background: #beebb3;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin: 4px;
    color: green;
}

.r {
  background-image: url('img/refresh2.png');
  background-size: contain;

}

.refresh {
  outline: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  top: 108px;
  opacity: 0;

}

.tree {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}


img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 13px #222;
  border: solid 3px #606f46;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
    <div id="no1">
      <div class="tree">
        <div class="avatar">
          <img src="https://entertainment.time.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2013/05/fictioninfluence_list_homersimpson.jpg">
        </div>
        <button id="btn1" class="refresh r"> </button>
        <span id="spn1" class="name">
          <input class="name_input" type="text" disabled="true" value="Homer Simpson">
          <div class="namefunc">
            <button class="check">Save</button>
            <button class="close">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="tree">
        <div class="avatar">
          <img class="white_bg" src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/theultimatesimpsons/images/0/0f/Marge-Simpson-icon.png/revision/latest?cb=20180210061653">
        </div>
        <button id="btn2" class="refresh r"></button>
        <span id="spn2" class="name">
          <input class="name_input" type="text" disabled="true" value="Marge Simpson">
          <div class="namefunc">
            <button class="check">Save</button>
            <button class="close">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JS, just because you call the variable `img` doesn't mean that you are working with the image element, you are working with `div.tree` nodes.

##### Addendum: per OP *"I need the button to not disappear when hovering over the image and then over the button"*

Move the buttons inside `.avatar` and act on the avatar mouse events:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".tree").forEach(tn => {
  let ava = tn.querySelector(".avatar");
  let btn = tn.querySelector(".avatar .r");

  ava.onmouseover = function() {
    btn.style.opacity = 1;
  };

  ava.onmouseout = function() {
    btn.style.opacity = 0;
  };
});
```

```css
#no1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 190px;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin: auto;
}

.container1 {
  width: 580px;
  font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.namefunc {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.name {
  background: #beebb3;
  border-color: #606f46;
  border-radius: 22px 0 22px 0;
  padding: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-top: 5px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 13px #222;
  width: 145px;
  color: green;
}

.name_input {
  background: #beebb3;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin: 4px;
  color: green;
}

.r {
  background-image: url('img/refresh2.png');
  background-size: contain;
}

.refresh {
  outline: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  top: 108px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.tree {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 13px #222;
  border: solid 3px #606f46;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div id="no1">
    <div class="tree">
      <div class="avatar">
        <img src="https://entertainment.time.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2013/05/fictioninfluence_list_homersimpson.jpg">
        <button id="btn1" class="refresh r"> </button>
      </div>
      <span id="spn1" class="name">
          <input class="name_input" type="text" disabled="true" value="Homer Simpson">
          <div class="namefunc">
            <button class="check">Save</button>
            <button class="close">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="tree">
      <div class="avatar">
        <img class="white_bg" src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/theultimatesimpsons/images/0/0f/Marge-Simpson-icon.png/revision/latest?cb=20180210061653">
        <button id="btn2" class="refresh r"></button>
      </div>
      <span id="spn2" class="name">
          <input class="name_input" type="text" disabled="true" value="Marge Simpson">
          <div class="namefunc">
            <button class="check">Save</button>
            <button class="close">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I need the button to not disappear when hovering over the image and then over the button –

Comment: Updated, see JS changes

Comment: FWIW: You don't need the JS, you can accomplish the same effect with Just CSS:

Comment: Thank you for your help @fnostro, the goal was to use just JS

Comment: Understood. Happy Coding. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `.forEach` loop is iterating over your `div.tree` elements and then adding mouseover and mouseout event handlers to those `div` elements, rather than looping over the actual `img` elements within the `div.tree` elements.

You also should really be using the modern `.addEventListener()` method to set up event callbacks, which is more powerful than using event properties, such as `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".tree img").forEach(img => {
  img.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
   img.closest(".tree").querySelector(".r").style.opacity = 1;
  });
  img.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
   img.closest(".tree").querySelector(".r").style.opacity = 0;
  });
});
```

```css
#no1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 190px;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin: auto;
}

.container1 {
  width: 580px;
  font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.namefunc {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.name {
  background: #beebb3;
  border-color: #606f46;
  border-radius: 22px 0 22px 0;
  padding: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-top: 5px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 13px #222;
  width: 145px;
  color: green;
}

.name_input {
    background: #beebb3;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin: 4px;
    color: green;
}

.r {
  background-image: url('img/refresh2.png');
  background-size: contain;

}

.refresh {
  outline: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  top: 108px;
  opacity: 0;

}

.tree {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}


img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 13px #222;
  border: solid 3px #606f46;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
    <div id="no1">
      <div class="tree">
        <div class="avatar">
          <img src="https://entertainment.time.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2013/05/fictioninfluence_list_homersimpson.jpg">
        </div>
        <button id="btn1" class="refresh r"> </button>
        <span id="spn1" class="name">
          <input class="name_input" type="text" disabled="true" value="Homer Simpson">
          <div class="namefunc">
            <button class="check">Save</button>
            <button class="close">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="tree">
        <div class="avatar">
          <img class="white_bg" src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/theultimatesimpsons/images/0/0f/Marge-Simpson-icon.png/revision/latest?cb=20180210061653">
        </div>
        <button id="btn2" class="refresh r"></button>
        <span id="spn2" class="name">
          <input class="name_input" type="text" disabled="true" value="Marge Simpson">
          <div class="namefunc">
            <button class="check">Save</button>
            <button class="close">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Beat me to it :). But I handled the JS a bit differently.

Comment: @fnostro Yes, you've added more than is really needed.

Comment: True, the intent was to clarify the original code to the author.  The variables were misleading.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Why the button disappears on hovering the image, then hovering over button?

Comment: @Vladimir Because the images have a callback that says that when the mouse is off of them, the opacity of the refresh button should be 0.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.avatar` selector and `nextElementSibling` to get refresh button

```
document.querySelectorAll(".tree .avatar").forEach(img => {
  img.onmouseover = function () {
    let refresh_button = img.nextElementSibling;
    refresh_button.style.opacity = 1;
  };
  img.onmouseout = function () {
    let refresh_button = img.nextElementSibling;
    refresh_button.style.opacity = 0;
  };
});
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".tree .avatar").forEach(img => {
  img.onmouseover = function () {
    let refresh_button = img.nextElementSibling;
    refresh_button.style.opacity = 1;
  };
  img.onmouseout = function () {
    let refresh_button = img.nextElementSibling;
    refresh_button.style.opacity = 0;
  };
});
```

```css
#no1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 190px;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin: auto;
}

.container1 {
  width: 580px;
  font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.namefunc {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.name {
  background: #beebb3;
  border-color: #606f46;
  border-radius: 22px 0 22px 0;
  padding: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-top: 5px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 13px #222;
  width: 145px;
  color: green;
}

.name_input {
    background: #beebb3;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin: 4px;
    color: green;
}

.r {
  background-image: url('img/refresh2.png');
  background-size: contain;

}

.refresh {
  outline: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  top: 108px;
  opacity: 0;

}

.tree {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}


img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 13px #222;
  border: solid 3px #606f46;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
    <div id="no1">
      <div class="tree">
        <div class="avatar">
          <img src="https://entertainment.time.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2013/05/fictioninfluence_list_homersimpson.jpg">
        </div>
        <button id="btn1" class="refresh r"> </button>
        <span id="spn1" class="name">
          <input class="name_input" type="text" disabled="true" value="Homer Simpson">
          <div class="namefunc">
            <button class="check">Save</button>
            <button class="close">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="tree">
        <div class="avatar">
          <img class="white_bg" src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/theultimatesimpsons/images/0/0f/Marge-Simpson-icon.png/revision/latest?cb=20180210061653">
        </div>
        <button id="btn2" class="refresh r"></button>
        <span id="spn2" class="name">
          <input class="name_input" type="text" disabled="true" value="Marge Simpson">
          <div class="namefunc">
            <button class="check">Save</button>
            <button class="close">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I need the button to not disappear when hovering over the image and then over the button